# JavaFX Scene builder display variable on start program

Tags: javafx

Hello I try to do something like getData from MySQL on start method in JavaFX

Now in Intellji I click "Run program" and then window is appear on the screen.

I have one Button "Get data" and after I clicked on it I get data from Mysql to show it in Label.

It is some solution that when we click "Run program" and JavaFX show window of our program and this Data from MySQL will be automatically display in label?

I mean how to run method getData(get data from MySQL) in public void start?

I display variable "Label labelek;" after click Button 
"Label labelek;" is in getData method

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 275));

        DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();    
        primaryStage.show();
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);    
    }
}
```

DBConnect

```
package sample;    
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;    
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;
    @FXML
    public Label labelek;

    //utworzenie konstruktora
    public DBConnect(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxx","xxx",
                    "xxx");
            st = con.createStatement();

        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
    public void getData(){
        try {
            String query = "select * from x order by id desc limit 1";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Records from DataBase");
            while(rs.next()){                   
                String TemperaturaPow = rs.getString("TemperaturaPow");

         labelek.setText("Temperature is " + temperathure);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Label labelek` from `DBConnect` class. Create separate `SampleController` class, in `initalize()` method  invoke `DBConnect connect = new DBConnect()` and attach your data to `Label labelek`.

**SampleController**

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label labelek;
    @FXML
    private Button getDataButton;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        DBConnect connect = new DBConnect(); 
        String data = connect.getData();
        labelek.setText(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer I create SimpleController and after create It, IDEA  prompted me to add to public String getData ->  "return getData" because without it getData do not return anything. When we start the program we can see JavaFX window with Button but without automatic load data from MySQL :/  .  Button loops getData method :)

Comment: Yes from `getData()` replace `labelek.setText("Temperature is " + temperathure);` with `return TemperaturaPow;`

Comment: I add `return TemperaturaPow()` instead `labelek.setText()` but IDEA still want `return` after `public String getData(){} return <---` so I add `return = getData` hmm for beginners always wind blowing to eyes :)

Comment: It still needs `return` statement because you are returning value from `try catch` block. Add `return null;` after `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

After I click Button with onAction (SceneBuilder) getData I can only see in IDEA
"Records from DataBase"  without TemperaturaPow :/

Controller Class in Scene Builder is : sample.DBConnect

It is really so difficult ;P?

```
public String getData(){
    try {
        String query = "select * from danet order by id desc limit 1";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Records from DataBase");
        while(rs.next()){
            String DataCzas = rs.getString("dataczas");
            String TemperaturaPow = rs.getString("TemperaturaPow");
            String WilgotnoscPow = rs.getString("WilgotnoscPow");
            String Cisnienie = rs.getString("baro");
            String dewPoint = rs.getString("dewPoint");
            String heatIndexC = rs.getString("heatIndexc");
            String comment = rs.getString("comment");
            return TemperaturaPow;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }


    return null;
}
```

public class SampleController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private Label labelek;
@FXML
private Button getDataButton;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
    String data = connect.getData();
    labelek.setText(data);
}
```

[PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeK9D.png)

Comment: I created new `class Controller` and in this class I create `public void DBData()`  in this method I insert all code to connect to MySQL and get data from it. Then I run this method in `void initialize()` and everything works :)